# SyntaxError Invalid Token (GPS Coordinates)

Tags: python, gps

First of all, I hope everyone's okay.
Now, my problem is that, when I want to assign 48,0162 as a y coordinate to a point, python tells me that the token is invalid (ik that 0 is a non-octal number and...).
So my question is, how can I write 48,0162 without inducting python systems in error ?

Thanks in advance,
Gwenn

```
#route
class Point():
    "airfield coordinates"
    LFST = Point()
    LFST.x = 7,6305
    LFST.y = 48,5353
    LFGA = Point()
    LFGA.x = 7,3555
    LFGA.y = 480,162/10

def route(departurex,departurey,arrivalx,arrivaly):
    vx=arrivalx-departurex
    vy=arrivaly-departurey
    scal=vx*vy+1
```

Comment: can we see your code？

Comment: @DustyPosa and I have another problem: the Point "name" is not defined

Comment: You should always try to provide a clear context and produce a minimal example. You have posted code and much of it is not relevant to your question. I understand that this might not always be easy to do that if one is new to programming. For example removing `def route` as it should be clear that that has nothing to do with how to assign your geo coordinate. You should also post the error message that you got. I know they might be hard to understand at first. But they do provide a lot of information for us to help you with.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point numbers should use a dot `.` not a comma `,`. In some countries (like Sweden) we use commas as decimal separators, but in programming languages a `.` is generally used.

So `LFST.y = 48,5353` should be `LFST.y = 48.5353` for example.